# how could I use parameter for employees in each year in plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

How I could add employees each year under 'Acquire since YYYY' in their year I find a way for a week and still don't know how it's work
This is my statement

```sql
DECLARE
    CURSOR c_year IS SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM hire_date) YEAR, COUNT(*) PERSON
                    FROM employees
                    GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM hire_date)
                    ORDER BY 1 ASC;
    CURSOR c_emp (thisyear NUMBER) IS   SELECT employee_id ID, first_name, last_name , hire_date
                                        FROM employees
                                        WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date) = thisyear
                                        ORDER BY 1 ASC;
BEGIN
    FOR e_year IN c_year LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Acquire since '|| e_year.YEAR || ' ('||e_year.PERSON || ' persons) ==========');
            FOR e_emp IN c_emp(8) LOOP
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: '||e_emp.ID||' '||e_emp.first_name||' '||e_emp.last_name);
            END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

And This is result

```
Acquire since 2001 (1 persons) ==========
Acquire since 2002 (7 persons) ==========
Acquire since 2003 (6 persons) ==========
Acquire since 2004 (10 persons) ==========
Acquire since 2005 (29 persons) ==========
Acquire since 2006 (24 persons) ==========
Acquire since 2007 (19 persons) ==========
Acquire since 2008 (11 persons) ==========
```

But I want employee's detail under each line by their year
what should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `e_Year.YEAR` into the parameterized cursor instead of the static value `8`:

```sql
DECLARE
  CURSOR c_year IS
    SELECT EXTRACT (YEAR FROM hire_date) YEAR, COUNT(*) PERSON
    FROM employees
    GROUP BY EXTRACT (YEAR FROM hire_date)
    ORDER BY 1 ASC;

  CURSOR c_emp (thisyear NUMBER) IS
    SELECT employee_id ID, first_name, last_name , hire_date
    FROM employees
    WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date) = thisyear
    ORDER BY 1 ASC;
BEGIN
  FOR e_year IN c_year LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Acquire since '|| e_year.YEAR || ' ('||e_year.PERSON || ' persons) ==========');
    FOR e_emp IN c_emp(e_year.year) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ID: '||e_emp.ID||' '||e_emp.first_name||' '||e_emp.last_name);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees ( employee_id, first_name, last_name, hire_date ) AS
SELECT 1, 'Alice', 'Abbot', DATE '2001-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Betty', 'Baron', DATE '2001-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Carol', 'Count', DATE '2001-03-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Debra', 'Duke',  DATE '2002-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Emily', 'Earl',  DATE '2002-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Fiona', 'Friar', DATE '2003-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Gerri', 'Grace', DATE '2004-01-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Acquire since 2001 (3 persons) ==========
> ID: 1 Alice Abbot
> ID: 2 Betty Baron
> ID: 3 Carol Count
> Acquire since 2002 (2 persons) ==========
> ID: 4 Debra Duke
> ID: 5 Emily Earl
> Acquire since 2003 (1 persons) ==========
> ID: 6 Fiona Friar
> Acquire since 2004 (1 persons) ==========
> ID: 7 Gerri Grace
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0RtIX_DA)

Comment: Thank you so much !! You just save me for exam in 10 hours I'm very appreciate

Answer (score 0):

You can run it also in a single query:

```
SELECT 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date) AS "Acquire since", 
    COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date)) "persons",
    'ID: '||employee_id||' '||first_name||' '||last_name AS ID
FROM employees
ORDER BY 1 ASC;
```

The output format is just a little different.